# What does this mean 公方さまの、表に出してはならぬような声も気にならぬほどで

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english, conversations

Context : 1 subordinate of a general (Kubou sama is JP general /shogunate i think ?) said this to her after go into an open hot spring outside.

**まったくですな。公方さまの、表に出してはならぬような声も気にならぬほどで**

What does she mean by this ? My guess is **"Really,you don't even care about your speaking tone as a general which is not supposed to be spoken out loud"**
Is she not supposed to be speaking loud or exposed her voice to public ?
If my understanding is wrong please correct me thanks

Comment: Could you paste a few original sentences before this, like you did before? It's not impossible to make a wild guess, but I'd like to answer with confidence. You have ignored ほど at the end of the sentence in your translation attempt, but it refers to something mentioned in the previous sentence.

Comment: The general only said 1 line before that "Fuwaa,what a nice hot spring ..." This is the beginning of a scene so I guess there is very little context

Comment: So the general said **"Fuwaa"** and praised the hot spring just before this? That's what we call the context! (By the way what's this Fuwaa in the original Japanese?) After all, まったく, ほど and 表に出してはならぬような声 all refer to what's been said in the previous line. There is no point in hiding such an important previous context and make others guess. It will only slow down the process of getting the right answer. Please [read this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ほど means "to the point where ～", "enough to ～". In this context, it refers to the previous line.
- 表に出す means "to publicize" or "to show something in public". 表に出してはならぬような声 is "the voice that must not be heard in the public", and it should refer to that "Fuwaa".
- Check the [difference between 気になる and 気にする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28425/5010). The subject of 気にならぬ is the subordinate.

> まったくですな。公方さまの、表に出してはならぬような声も気にならぬほどで。
>
> Indeed. (The hot spring is so good to the point where) even that [laid-back] voice of yours that must not be heard in public is not going to disturb me.

So this is a rather harsh and sarcastic remark on that "Fuwaa". The subordinate thought it lacked dignity and should not be said when someone is around. I imagine this subordinate is a rather blunt type.

Comment: I get it now .Because the scene showing the characters standing near the open hot spring outside so I didn't thought that they're already "inside" the hot spring . The "mattaku desuna" まったくですな >> is the way the subordinate saying agree to the general comment about the hotspring (after she's already experienced the water) - and not complaining like I thought at first . Thanks